Does an ORCID alone convey any information?
Do the digits of an ORCID convey any information?
In particular, given two ORCIDs, can I infer anything about the order in which they were created? For example, if two ORCIDs had prefixes 0000-0001-6000 and 0000-0001-9000, respectively, would this imply that first was created before the second?

No, according to ORCID:

Initially ORCID iDs will be randomly assigned by the ORCID Registry from a block of numbers that will not conflict with ISNI-formatted numbers assigned in other ways. ORCID iDs always require all 16 digits of the identifier; they can not be shortened to remove leading zeros if they exist.
No information about a person is encoded in the ORCID iD. The identifiers were designed to be usable in situations where personally-identifiable information should/can not be shared. Also, since the ORCID iD is designed to be a career-long identifier, no information that can change over a person's career is embedded in the iD, e.g., country, institution, field of study.
Only the ORCID Registry can assign ORCID iDs. ORCID iDs are intended to be assigned to individuals and may be secured at no charge. ORCID iDs are assigned randomly from a block of numbers reserved for this purpose. Typically, the 16-digit identifiers are assigned between 0000-0001-5000-0007 and 0000-0003-5000-0001, or between 0009-0000-0000-0000 and 0009-0010-0000-0000.

According to a 24 February, 2023 update here
(see also this page):

Because we have over 16 million records, we required a new block of identifiers. ISNI, the organization ORCID coordinates with to release the 16-digit unique identifiers, has released a new range reserved for ORCID defined between 0009-0000-0000-0000 and 0009-0010-0000-0000.

So presumably an ORCID identifier between 0009-0000-0000-0000 and 0009-0010-0000-0000 implies a creation date after February 2023.
However you can also find the precise creation date in every ORCID profile.

Thanks! In late 2022 that page didn't mention the 0009-... range so maybe that signals a relatively new ORCID assignment?

Yes it seems so, according to 24 Feb 2023 update here: https://info.orcid.org/feature-friday/
